# How do I fetch data in select option during editing data looped from the database?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have an issue with my code. I am using a model to update data, but in my form there is select option where by when I need all data to be populated I found only one row populated in it. If I have to populate values in that option by using `<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {?>`. All row populated in that option field but in the list where all row of data needed to be populated, it populates only one.

```
<?php 
    include('../Tools/connection.php');
    $query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT abl_atms.atmCode,abl_atms.atmID,abl_atms.branchID, abl_branch.name,abl_branch.bid
                                FROM abl_atms
                                INNER JOIN abl_branch ON abl_branch.bid = abl_atms.branchID");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      $id = $row['atmID'];
      $id = $row['branchID']
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo strtoupper($row['atmID']);?></td>
          <td><?php echo ucwords($row['atmCode']).'- '.strtolower($row['name']);?></td>
          <td><?php echo strtoupper($row['name']);?></td>
          <td class="pull-right">
          <button class="btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" href="#atm<?php echo $row['atmID'];?>" 
                  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
          <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
          <button class="btn-danger btn-xs" title="Delete" data-toggle="modal"
                href="#delete<?php echo $row['atmID'];?>" data-toggle="tooltip">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        
        
        
        <div class="modal fade" id="atm<?php echo $row['atmID'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="card" style="border-left: 4px solid coral">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                      Update Atm information
                  </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form class="was-validated" action="abl_atms.php" method="POST">
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="bmd-label-static"><i class="fa fa-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></i> ATM CODE</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="atmCode" value="<?php echo ucwords($row['atmCode']);?>" placeholder="Type ATM Identification CODE" required>
                            </fieldset>
                            <input class="form-control" name="atmID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['atmID'];?>">
                            <fieldset class="form-group">
                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="bmd-label-static"><i class="fa fa-snowflake-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> ATM BRANCH</label>
                                <select class="custom-select" required name="branchID">
                                    <option value="">Select Branch Name</option>
                                    <?php
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                      ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row['branchID']; ?>"<?php if ($id == $row['branchID']) 
                                    { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option> 
                                    <?php 
                                        }
                                      ?>                        
                                </select>
                            </fieldset>                            
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-warning btn-block" name="editAtm">
                                  <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Confirm & Update
                                </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <?php 
          }
        ?>       
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be trying to loop the same mysql result set twice, the second of which is inside the first loop. That isn't going to work. If you need to loop a result set twice, you must first put the results into an array, and then loop over the array. If you loop a result set directly, you can only do it once.

Comment: Can you help me with just so code how i have to make it please? Am new to it

Comment: Well, which part of what I said didn't you understand exactly? Tell me if there's something I can explain better. Apart from that, you should at least try..that's how you learn. If you get stuck again then post your updated code here.

Comment: How to store result se into array and use that to loop in the select option

Comment: Well those are two separate tasks. Here's the first one: `$rows = array(); while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { $rows[] = $row; }`. Once that ends you have an array called `$rows`. You can use `foreach` to loop through it as many times as you like. Please don't ask me how to write the exact code for that, it's something you can learn easily by looking online...learning how to research and how to practice and implement other people's examples into your own code is a very important skill for a programmer. So please now go and practice it. Come back if you're stuck after actually trying.

Comment: It worked out but if i have to select first row, in a dropdown drop only one if fourth row selected four of them droped and if last one selected all of them get droped.

Comment: Sorry but that is very unclear. Try to write a clear description using proper sentences and punctuation, and ensure it relates to what you have been talking about before. Provide code and data examples to help explain. Edit it into your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store results in an array and then loop over results.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT abl_atms.atmCode,abl_atms.atmID,abl_atms.branchID,abl_branch.name,abl_branch.bid 
    FROM abl_atms 
    INNER JOIN abl_branch 
    ON abl_branch.bid = abl_atms.branchID");
$results = mysqli_fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($results as $v){
    // Your Code....
    foreach($results as $vi){
        // Your Selection Options...
    }
}
```